# ionic 2 exception handling without freezing

Tags: angular, ionic2

How can I make my app resilient to exceptions.

Currently, each time there is an exception, the UI freezes and I have to restart the app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Angular 2 ExceptionHandler](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ExceptionHandler-class.html).

> The default implementation of ExceptionHandler prints error messages
>   to the Console. To intercept error handling, write a custom exception
>   handler that replaces this default as appropriate for your app.

So you can create your own implementation of this class

```
class MyExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler {
  call(error, stackTrace = null, reason = null) {
    // do something with the exception
  }
}
```

And then, include it in your top-most component (the App component) like this:

```
import {ExceptionHandler,provide} from '@angular2/core';
import {MyExceptionHandler} from './folder/file-name';

@Component({
    providers: [provide(ExceptionHandler, {useClass: MyExceptionHandler})]
})
export class MyApp{...}
```

**UPDATE**

As of Ionic2 RC, in order to replace the `ExceptionHandler` for own custom implementation, we nee to include it in the `NgModule` like this:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyExceptionHandler}]
})
class MyModule {}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried that and I have an error `TypeScript error: app/app.ts(118,7): Error TS2420: Class 'MyExceptionHandler' incorrectly implements interface 'ExceptionHandler'.
  Property '_logger' is missing in type 'MyExceptionHandler'.` I' ve tried different things after but it still in error `roperty '_logger' is private in type 'ExceptionHandler' but not in type 'MyExceptionHandler'.` or `TypeScript error: app/app.ts(118,7): Error TS2420: Class 'MyExceptionHandler' incorrectly implements interface 'ExceptionHandler'.
  Types have separate declarations of a private property '_logger'`

Comment: If I don't implements the interface, there is an error in runtime `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`

Comment: Sorry about that, it's happening in my app too. It seems it's related to a bug on Angular2 (there are several issues like [this one](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6565), [this one](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8993) and [this one](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6865). Have you tried with [this workaround](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6865#issuecomment-179889736)? In that comment and in the next one, @tbragaf shared a workaround and seems to be working properly in my app.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it worked with the "workaround", and I had to use a factory for my custom handler, instead of "useClass"

Comment: everything i did but nothing willk happen

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** Latest angular2, there is `ErrorHandler` not `ExceptionHandler` in angular core, which is now `@angular/core` not `@angular2/core`.

```
import { ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';

export class MyExceptionHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(error) {
    // do something with the error
  }
}
```

Link to new angular class: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html